Capacitor JS Error building apk - Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'
I am having problems generating apks (and building in general) off android studio.
My application is built with Next.JS 14.1.4 and capacitor 6.

What i have tried
I have run the following steps multiple times:

close android studio
delete android folder
run npm run build
run npx cap add android
run npx cap sync
cleared android cache
sync project with gradle files

Update both gradle/AGP as suggested by android studio.
Modified gradle.properties like so
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Added multiDexEnabled true in build.gradle
Added buildTypes.release.crunchPngs false in build.gradle
Nothing of the above changed the error i am getting
This is the error i get when i try to build the project

This is my project configuration


next.config.mjs
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    distDir: "out",
    generateBuildId: async () => {
        // This could be anything, using the latest git hash
        return "ciaoooo";
    },
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [
            {
                protocol: "https",
                hostname: "**",
            },
        ],
    },
};

export default nextConfig;

capacitor.config.ts
import { CapacitorConfig } from "@capacitor/cli";

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
    appId: "com.timing.app",
    appName: "timing",
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    webDir: "out",
    server: {
        url: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000",
        cleartext: true,
    },
};

export default config;

My dependencies
  "dependencies": {
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/android-full-screen": "^6.7.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-avatar": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-icons": "^1.3.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.0.7",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "byte-base64": "^1.1.0",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.2",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "cmdk": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-fullscreen": "^1.3.0",
    "fetch-intercept": "^2.4.0",
    "geopattern": "^1.2.3",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "lucide-react": "^0.372.0",
    "next": "14.1.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.3",
    "react-icons": "^5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.5",
    "sass": "^1.72.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.3.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "vaul": "^0.9.0",
    "zod": "^3.23.3",
    "zustand": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/geopattern": "^1.2.9",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.4",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }

